# Bottom navigation view the icon is overlaping the text

Tags: android, material-design, bottomnavigationview

This is my problem when i add size into the icon the icon overlaps the text i have.

[Icon overlaps textview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7cAW.png)

and this is the xml code i have:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:elevation="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_nav"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/black"
        app:itemIconSize="36dp"

        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/black"
        app:menu="@menu/botton_nav_buttom"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Were you able to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

For your problem that the icon covers your text:

You can override some default dimensions of the bottom navigation view. For example the height.
In Values->Dimens add(adjust height accordingly)

`<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_height" tools:override="true">56dp</dimen>`